# Create trigger condition for count table row after delete

Tags: mysql, triggers

Is it possible to query first and count the number of row and use it as a condition and send mail notification.

My Visual Code is something like this:

```
Create Trigger test After Delete on table
   for each row
   Begin 
     Select count(*) as result from table
        if result = 0 then
          set column1 = 'empty'
          --or send mail if possible much better
        else:
          set column1 = 'full'
          --or send mail if possible much better
   End;
```

Any Suggestions or comments, Thanks in advance.